# Firebase functions (real time database): get the previous key of the created one

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Lets say I have a database structure that looks like this:

```
   Items
   |
   |--item1

   |--item2

   |--item3

   --.......
```

and lets say I have a function that listens to each added (item)

like that:

```
     exports.listen_to_added_items=functions.database.ref('Items/{item_id}').onCreate(event=>{



     });
```

Now I know that it is possible to get the id of the added item like that:

```
    var item_id=event.params.item_id;
```

But the question is, can we get the id of the previous item:

**EXAMPLE OF MY QUESTION**:

1) If item3 was added.

2) (listen_to_added_items) function will then trigger.

3) question: Is it possible to get the id of (item2)?

Comment: you cannot get the previous id, but you can get the previous data that was in that id

Comment: Why do you need to figure this out?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DougStevenson I need to make a database write at the previous id of each item.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What is the definition of "previous id" in your case?

Comment: @DougStevenson according to the above database structure, at the moment when item 3 is added I want to trigger a database write to item2...Hence I need (item 2) 's id.

Comment: There's no API for this.  You'll have to make a record of the previous id yourself, and access that safely between multiple updates using a transaction.

Comment: Are you inserting as `firebase.database().ref('/items').push({ ... });`? If so the push key should be and ordered list. You should then be able to run a query `firebase.database().ref('/items').orderByKey().endAt('currentKey').limitToLast(2)` this will get the last two keys - The key your using, and the one previous to it.